# xargs jar tvf - does not work

Tags: bash, xargs

Objective: to list files in all jars.

This works:

```
for f in `find . -name "*.jar"`; do jar tvf $f; done
```

This works too:

```
find . -name "*.jar" -exec jar tvf {} \;
```

This does not (it does not print any output):

```
find . -name "*.jar" | xargs jar tvf
```

Why does the latter not work?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Does this works

```
find . -name "*.jar"|xargs -n 1 jar -tvf
```

Answer (score 9):

The problem is that `jar tvf` only allows one file to be passed in.

The for loop runs the files one by one

```
jar tvf 1.jar; jar tvf 2.jar; ...
```

However, xargs tries to fit as many arguments on one line as possible. Thus it's trying the following:

```
jar tvf 1.jar 2.jar ...
```

You can verify this by placing an echo in your command:

```
for f in `find . -name "*.jar"`; do echo jar tvf $f; done
find . -name "*.jar" | xargs echo jar tvf
```

The proper solution is the tell xargs to only use one parameter per command:

```
find . -name "*.jar" | xargs -n 1 jar tvf
```

or

```
find . -name "*.jar" | xargs -I{} jar tvf {} # Find style parameter placement
```

Comment: @sarnold you have to know that this argument (`-i`) is deprecated. see man xargs (`xargs (GNU findutils) 4.4.2`): `This option is deprecated; use -I instead.` There is no problem to use it in interactive mode but I would avoid it in scripts since it could disapear in a futur versions of xargs.

Answer (score 6):

It does not work because xargs invoke only one process with all arguments.

There is a way to invoke a new process for each argument using `-I'{}'`.

Try this to understand:

```
$ seq 10 | xargs echo
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
$ seq 10 | xargs -I'{}' echo {}
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```